# NullReferenceException on unmanaged c++ code

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, unmanaged

I have a C++ DLL that I need to use in may c# project.

Here is the important part of my code:

```
public static class MTSCRA_API
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void DataReceiveDelegate([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String x);

    //More methods....

    [DllImport("MTSCRA.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void OnDeviceConnectionStateChanged(IntPtr lpFuncNotify);

}
```

Where I use it:

```
public void Open()
        {
            if (!MTSCRA_API.IsDeviceConnected())
            {
                UInt32 result = MTSCRA_API.OpenDevice("");
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    MTSCRA_API.OnDataReceived(
                        Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
                        new Kiosk.Hardware.CardReaderMagTek.MTSCRA_API.DataReceiveDelegate(CardReaderMagTek_OnCardDataReceived)));
                }
            }
    }

    Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
    void CardReaderMagTek_OnCardDataReceived(String info)
    {
        try
        {
             //Do stuff
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        MTSCRA_API.ClearCardData();
        info = null;

    }
```

Each time I swipe a card in a device, the `CardReaderMagTek_OnCardDataReceived()` event is called.

The `Open()` method is executed and the event `CardReaderMagTek_OnCardDataReceived()` is called but only 9 times. A the 10º the code crash with a NullReferenceException without entering in the event and I don't have access to the callstack...

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MTSCRA_API.OnDataReceived(
    Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
    new Kiosk.Hardware.CardReaderMagTek.MTSCRA_API.DataReceiveDelegate(
        CardReaderMagTek_OnCardDataReceived)
    )
);
```

You are not keeping your delegate alive. You create an instance of `DataReceiveDelegate` and pass it to `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. But after `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` returns, there's no reason for the delegate to stay alive. At some point it will be collected.

Hold the delegate in a managed variable for as long as the unmanaged function needs to be able to call it.

Comment: It was that! I spent too much time on this... Thanks.